# SQL Server dynamic inserts based on another table's rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've derived the following pseudo-coded script as a generic insert with variables that I want to replace for each row in another table (I can assume that the columns are always the same for the insert and select statements):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TNAME]
            --Replace with list of columns for [TNAME]
           ([craft]
           ,[description]
           ,[craftid])
    SELECT 
        --Replace with list of columns for [TNAME]
       [craft]
      ,[description]
      ,coalesce(const.maxs, 0) + row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
  FROM [altdb].[dbo].[TNAME] cross join
  (select max([IDCOL]) as maxs from [TNAME]) const
  where [altdb].[dbo].[TNAME].[PRIMARYCOL] not in (select [PRIMARYCOL] from [TNAME])
```

The variables that I want to replace are: [TNAME], [IDCOL], [PRIMARYCOL] from the [altdb].[dbo].[LISTOFTABLES] table that looks like this:

```
  TNAME  |  IDCOL   |  PRIMARYCOL
  ------------------------------
  TABLE1 | TABLE1ID |    T1
  TABLE2 | TABLE2ID |    T2
  TABLE3 | TABLE3ID |    T3
```

So with the example list of tables above I want to be able to output 3 copies of the first script but with values for that row substituted into the variables and dynamically listing all the columns for that table in the INSERT and SELECT statements. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: You are going to have to use dynamic SQL to get what you want.  You can query sys.columns to get a list of columns for a given table.

Comment: @JonathanFite Do you have any simple examples for dynamic queries I could take a look at? It would be very helpful

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html